# BG Processing task

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, background, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to use BGProcessingTask in my application, when I test, my code is executed only once, but my task is to run it as in the example at the exhibition wwdc2019.
I need that after the user closes the application, every 15 minutes this code works and sends data to the server **What am I doing wrong ?**

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: 
    
        [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
         if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                    BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.transistorsoft.process", using: nil) { (task) in
                        self.handleBackgroundProcess(task: task as! BGProcessingTask)
                    }
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
                return true
        }
         @available(iOS 13.0, *)
            func handleBackgroundProcess(task:BGProcessingTask) {
                schedularProcessTask()
                bgTask(task: task)
            }
        
            
            @available(iOS 13.0, *)
            func bgTask(task:BGProcessingTask) {
                let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timestamp <%@", NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: -24 * 60 * 60))
                
                task.expirationHandler = {
                    BGTaskScheduler.shared.cancelAllTaskRequests()
                }
                
                let location = LocationObj()
                let lat = location.lat ?? 0
                let lon = location.lon ?? 0
                let accuracy = location.accuracy
                var taskId = "123"
                
                let endpoint = CheckTaskGeolocationEndpoint(taskId:taskId, lat: lat, lon: lon, accuracy: accuracy)
                endpoint.apiCall { (result, error) in
                    if error?.success ?? false {
                        if result?.autoExit == true {
                            ReminderNotificationManager.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(tite: "You are not in the polygon",
                                                                                         body: "Task is over")
                            BGTaskScheduler.shared.cancelAllTaskRequests()
                        }else {
                            ReminderNotificationManager.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(tite: "You are in the polygon",
                            
                                                                                         body: "All good")
                            print(predicate)
/// task was complete and wait when task is run again
                            task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
                        }
                    } else {
/// task was complete and wait when task is run again
                        task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
                    }
                }
            }
```

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```
func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        schedularProcessTask()
    }

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func schedularProcessTask() {
    let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: "com.transistorsoft.process")
    request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15 * 60)
    request.requiresNetworkConnectivity = true
    do {
        try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        
    }catch {
        print("Could not schedule app refresh \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: "I need that after the user closes the application, every 15 minutes this code works and sends data to the server." This is impossible. There is no mechanism in iOS that allows you to perform an operation at known periods. You can request it, but the OS does not promise it (and generally won't give it to you). The closest you can get is to send push notifications, but they don't promise to launch your app, but generally will. If you need this, you'll need to redesign to not need it.

Comment: You absolutely cannot track a user's location every 15 minutes. You can turn on full location tracking, which is fairly battery intensive and requires ongoing user permission. Or you can use `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, which is probably closer to what you're looking for, but is only accurate to fairly large areas (~500m, but can be more). Or you can use iBeacons (but then you have to deploy iBeacons).

Comment: @RobNapier Okay, thanks) If I set the region for `startMonitoring (for: CLRegion)`, and the user closes the application, can I track when he leaves the location and send it to the server?

Comment: Yes, CLRegion monitoring is generally quite robust as well. It is also very low-power.

Comment: @RobNapier Ok, you can write this as an answer and I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

The tool you likely want here is `startMonitoring(for:)` to monitor within a region. You cannot launch you app reliably at some time interval, and if you did it would be very bad for battery life. But region monitoring is battery-efficient and generally the OS will launch you when needed.

Other tools you can explore are `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, push notifications, and iBeacons. But for this particular problem, region monitoring is probably the most effective.